# Convert a Spark DataFrame into a list of objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oop, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I know that it is possible to convert a dataframe column into a list using something like:

```
dataFrame.select("ColumnName").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
```

Let's say I already know the schema of the dataframe and correspondingly I created a case class such as :

```
case class Synonym(URI: String, similarity: Double, FURI: String)
```

is there an efficient way to get a list of Synonym objects from the data of the dataframe?

In other words, I am trying to create a mapper that would convert each row of the dataframe into an object of my **case class** and then return this object in a way that I can have a list of these objects at the end of the operation. is this possible in an efficient nice way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `as[Synonym]` to get a `Dataset[Synonym]` which you can then `collect` to get an `Array[Synonym]`:

```
val result = dataframe.as[Synonym].collect()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use typed `Dataset`:

```
df.select("URI", "similarity", "FURI").as[Synonym].collect
```